# Menu Strip Control "Window"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, menuitem, menustrip

I am working on a project and am just stymied by this. It should be really straight forward. I have included the code so you can see the other Menu Strip Items.

The user has the ability to open as many "Child" forms into the mdiParent form. I would like the "Window" function on the menu strip to populate with the Bank Name found on the Child form so if a user had 10 bank forms open, they could find a specific form by clicking Window and seeing the bank name (the name of the text field which I would like to pull is Bank.lblbank.text) This functionality was found in the 2007 and older versions of many of the Microsoft Suite products.

If I hadn't seen my professor do this in class, I would think it was a bit of proprietary Microsoft Office coding that us mere mortals cannot access.  Unfortunately, he whipped it out and I didn't get it captured.

Obviously, I am not asking the right questions on the search engines because I cannot find a clear answer. Does anyone have any advice? This functionality isn't necessary but a little something I want to add. I've worked on this way too long and just want a little bit of success.

Let me know if a zip copy of the project or screen prints would be helpful.  I'm happy to send them your way.

Appreciate everyone looking at this post and their feedback. Thank you for your time!

Lauren

```
Public Class Loan_Evaluator

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewLoanToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewLoanToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim NewBank As New Bank
        NewBank.MdiParent = Me
        NewBank.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub VerticalToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VerticalToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CascadeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CascadeToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HorizontalToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HorizontalToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WindowToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WindowToolStripMenuItem.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the main **MenuStrip** control, not the ToolStripMenuItem.  So you'd click on MenuStrip1, not WindowToolStripMenuItem, for example.  Now change the MdiWindowListItem() property to "Window" (or whatever menu item you want to be populated with open MdiChildren).  Done.

Comment: You are brilliant! I was able to get it to work. Now. . . I would like to take I one step further. When I open several of my child forms, it simply lists them as 1, 2, 3, etc. instead of the text field that is the title of that form. (Bank.lblBankNm.text) I have tried to call this out in several places with no avail. I am wondering if I need to identify that as a mdiChildForm. If so where exactly to you put this under properties for the ToolStripMenuItem or under the Window selection on that ToolStripMenuItem.

Thank you so much! I appreciate your help on this.

Lauren